# Is it true that all matrices of this type are involutory?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, involutions

I came across a problem that suggested the following for a $3 \times 3$ matrix.
$$\text{Let } H = I - \frac{2}{3}A$$
$$\text{Then } H^2 = I$$
For $H, A \in M_{3,3}$ and $A$ being a matrix of all ones. I played around with this and found that for $H, A \in M_{n,n}$ and $A$ being a matrix of all ones
$$\text{Let } H = I - \frac{2}{n}A$$
$$\text{Then } H^2 = I$$
Works in the cases for $0 \leq n \leq 4$, which makes me think it's probably true for any $n$. Is that the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, it is known that the $n\times n$ matrix of all ones is such that $A^2=nA$. To show this, see that every entry is going to be the sum of $n$ products of ones:
\begin{align*}
A^2&=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n1 & \sum_{i=1}^n1 & \cdots & \sum_{i=1}^n1\\
\sum_{i=1}^n1 & \sum_{i=1}^n1 & \cdots & \sum_{i=1}^n1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\sum_{i=1}^n1 & \sum_{i=1}^n1 & \cdots & \sum_{i=1}^n1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
n & n & \cdots & n\\
n & n & \cdots & n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
n & n & \cdots & n
\end{bmatrix}=nA.
\end{align*}
Then, we get
\begin{align}
H^2=\left(I-\frac{2}{n}A\right)\left(I-\frac{2}{n}A\right)=I^2&-\frac{2}{n}IA-\frac{2}{n}AI+\frac{4}{n^2}A^2\\
&=I-\frac{4}{n}A+\frac{4}{n^2}(nA)=I-\frac{4}{n}A+\frac{4}{n}A=I.
\end{align}